# Unit Test a 3X3 or 4X4 Determinant

Tags: c++, unit-testing, math

Are there any mathematical properties similar to A * A<sup>-1</sup> = I that can be used to test the calculation of the determinant in a unit test like format?

Comment: What do you mean by "to the test the calculation of the determinant" ? You mean if you can invert a matrix? Gauss-Jordan elimination could be used to check if the matrix is inveritble

Comment: I think the OP wants to verify the determinant calculation using some known characteristic (e.g. "verifying" the inverse by multiplying by the original and getting the identity array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the determinant of a known array (or arrays) manually and compare your result to that number.

Try arrays of different sizes, arrangements, etc.

By the way I would NOT use A * A<sup>-1</sup> = I as a definitive test of inverse or multiplication.  Unit tests typically test *one thing* against a *specific, constant* result.  Testing two offsetting operations could lead to false positives - e.g. your "multiply" code could just return the constant identity array and your test would not fail.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant.
Some of those are fairly straightforward to check in a unit test (e.g. det(I) = 1, det(A<sup>T</sup>) = det(A), and det(cA) = c<sup>n</sup> det(A)), either directly or used to derive specific 'corner cases'.

There are others properties dependent on the correct implementation of other matrix manipulations. This can make them slightly less interesting for unit testing purposes since you can't as easily pinpoint a test failure.

Answer (score 0):

You could get some test cases using [Sylvester's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) In the notation of the link, if you take A to be a column vector and B to be a row vector then the right hand side is the determinant of a scalar, which is just that scalar.

More explicitly I'm saying that if A and B are vectors and M the matrix

```
M[i,j] = I[i,j] + A[i]*B[j]
```

(I the identity matrix) then

```
det( M) = 1 + Sum{ i | A[i]*B[i]}
```